# Get all elments on page thats possible overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a spinoff from this question

[Detect if clicking outside of element (Must support clicking in overlay elements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109625/detect-if-clicking-outside-of-element-must-support-clicking-in-overlay-elements/17169973)

In the code found in my question i do

```
var possibleOverlays = $("[style*=z-index],[style*=absolute]").not(":hidden");
```

To get all possible overlays (Like datepicker, dialogs etc). This is anything but rock solid. It requires that the datepicker or popover uses inline styles. Is there a more rock solid way of getting all overlays on the page?

With overlay I mean elements that floats over other elements

Comment: What is the use case? There might be a better way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: For more details on use case see linked question, but in short I want to hide a element if clicked outside of it. But not if clicked in a overlay that overlays the element that I want to hide

Comment: IMHO, you'd be better off finding a way to uniquely identify the overlay elements (maybe common class names?) and using the method to prevent click propagation mentioned in the linked question.

Comment: No, I want it to be general for all kinds of overlays. This is a large project and I cant have it break every time another dev brings in a new kind of overlay

Comment: Expanding on @zdyn 's comment, I would recommend adding `data` attribute to all your overlay elements (rather than a class), so you'd have something like `<div class="..." id="..." data-type="overlay">` - and then use selector `$('[data-type="overlay"]')`

Comment: Guys these are third party libraries